# Google Conversion tracking with a Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, event-tracking

I am receiving the following error on my Chrome Extension:

> Refused to load the script
>   'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxxxxxxx' because it
>   violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
>   'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com". Note that 'script-src-elem' was
>   not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

This is the what i have in the popup.html of my extension:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-xxxxxxxxx">
</script>
```

The rest of the conversion code has been moved to the the popup.js

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'AW-xxxxxxxxx');


window.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  if(e.target.href!==undefined){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:e.target.href})
  }
})

gtag('event', 'conversion', {
    'send_to': 'AW-xxxxxxxxx/aaaaaaaaaa',
    'transaction_id': ''
});
```

This is the security policy in the manifest

```
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Is it possible to track conversions in a chrome extension?

Comment: I don't see www.googletagmanager.com in your content_security_policy string. Why?

Comment: I did not realize I needed to. I just tried it, and had to change to 'unsafe-inline' which seems to remove the value of CSP. Is there another way to track conversions without tagmanager? or is this security risk acceptable?

Comment: Generally it's a bad idea. When loading script externally, you basically trust in your user's network stack not being hacked/subverted.

Comment: I'm assuming there must be another way to do conversion tracking then. Maybe I shouldn't be using google tag manager